# how to GET specific item using id using request module

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, request

I am ultimately wanting to GET a specific id from a RESTful web service, modify it and PUT it back (update it). The code that follows GETs everything from the web service, how can I modify it just to get a specific id?

```
request({
  url: url,                                        // URL to hit
  qs: { from: 'blog example', time: +new Date() }, // Query string data
  method: 'GET',                                   // Specify the method
}, function(error, response, body) {
  if (error) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express', data: []});
  } else {
    console.log(body);
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express', data: JSON.parse(body) });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If my server returned a user based on his/her id:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var users = [
  {id: 1, name: 'wilson'},
  {id: 2, name: 'santiago'}
];

app.get('/users/:userId', function(req, res) {
  var userId = Number(req.params.userId);
  var userFound = null;

  users.map(function(user) {
    if (user.id === userId) {
      userFound = user;
    }
  });

  res.send({user: userFound});
});

app.listen(4040, function() {
  console.log('server up and running at 4040');
});
```

then I would consume my server passing the id of `1` in route `/users/:userId`:

```
var request = require('request');
var URL_SERVER = 'http://localhost:4040';
var URL = URL_SERVER + '/users/1';

request({
  url: URL,
  method: 'GET'
}, function(err, response, body) {
  var result = JSON.parse(body);

  // getting only the user with the id of 1.
  console.log(result); // { user: { id: 1, name: 'wilson' } }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 

  const express = require('express');
  const port = 3000;
  const app = express();
  let support = const support = require('./support.json');

  app.get('/support/:userId', function(req, res) {
    var users = support
    var userId = Number(req.params.userId);
    console.log(userId)
    users.map(function(user) {
      if (user.id === userId) {
        res.send(user)
      }
    });
  });

  app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Servidor iniciado en el puerto ${port}`) 
  );

  module.exports = app;
```

This will return the data of the object in the route 'support' with id 'support/{id}' as `{"id":1,"setEmail":"setEmail@example.com","setMessage":"setMessage@example.com"}`